# Sum of rows in DataTable -- invalid cast?

Tags: c#

1.) ***Ok, so I have my DataTable that is imported from an Excel SpreadSheet and it is filled.I would like to sift through the DataTable and sum each row. I have to skip the first column & the first rows because they are labels. I am trying to reach each row in the table and total it and output to a "Row Total" column .. I am getting a "invalid cast specified" when I am trying to assign the 'number' variable to try and sum each cells value.

Example:
Row(0)    --------------------ItemA......ItemB.......ItemC..............RowTotal

Column(1) CompanyA   .....12     ..........12.............10....................34

2.) Also, I haven't reached it yet -- there is a potential issue with my trying to output it to the last column in the DataTable.

noted by:   ***dr[dt.Columns.Count - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(sum);***

Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            int sum = 0;
            dt.Columns.Add("Row Totals", typeof(int));

         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Client")
                {
                    dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1);

                       int number =0;

                       number = (dt.Rows[j].Field<int>(i));

                        sum += number;

                        dr[dt.Columns.Count - 1] = Convert.ToInt32(sum);


               Console.WriteLine("Row : {0} , Column : {1} , Value : {2}", i,j, dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(sum);
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

UPDATE: 12/27/12 ************************

So, a solution I'm trying is to just skip the rows and column I know are text. I am still getting the "specified cast not valid" when it tries to filter through each cell and sum it. Any more suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

```
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            int sum = 0;
            int number = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count-1; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "column1")
                {
                    dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(0);

                }
                if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "column2")
                {
                    dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1);
                }
                else
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(0);
                        dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1);


                        //if (number != -1 && number != 0)
                        //{

                            number = (dt.Rows[j].Field<int>(i));
                            sum += number;
                            dr[dt.Rows.Count] = Convert.ToInt32(sum);
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    number = 0;
                        //}


                        Console.WriteLine("Row : {0} , Column : {1} , Value : {2}", i, j, dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(sum);


                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();

                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
```

****UPDATE 12/27 1:30pm
I have scratched all that previous code and am attempting a test sheet and output. It seems to be working except now I can't seem to get the items to total when I am adding them to the last row. I'm stuck in the "else"" section of the code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count - 2; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                string value = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                int num = 0;
                bool res = int.TryParse(value, out num);
                if (res == false)
                {
                    num = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int sum = 0;

                    sum += num;
                    DataRow dr;
                   dr["Totals"] = sum;
                   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that there is a blank value in your data table - you can't cast a null object to an integer, so the Field extension method may be failing.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that I can add on that "IsNull" -- correct?

Comment: @scottO check if its not null then perform the sum.

Comment: I did a check for '-1' because it said I couldn't use IsNull with an int.. It is passing and now not finding column 18

Comment: Alright, so -- I have moved past the "specified cast not valid" by inserting a 0. Now, It says it "cant find column 17" -- The index is only to 16 though so I don't understand why it is looking for a 17th column?

Comment: The full exact error text would be useful. Also, what value is dt.Columns.Count - 1?

Comment: The "dt.Columns.Count -1" is me trying to offset it, and so it goes to Column 16 and then throws the error -- the exact error message is "Cannot find column 17."

Comment: **Edit on that third comment-- I'd been trying to add a column but realized it is already there. So, I'm currently stuck at it looking for that 17th column.

Comment: So you now want to ignore the last column in your table? Then you need

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count-2; i++)